# Moving powershell script from a local machine to the cloud, made the script run partially, or not at all, why?

Tags: powershell

I have this simple code:

```
function CEMDatabaseConnect
    {
        Add-Content $ExtendedLogFile "### 1.4 function CEMDatabaseConnect Start $(Get-Date)"
        param([string]$query=$(throw 'query is required.'))
        Add-Content $ExtendedLogFile "################## CEMDatabaseConnect 1 $(Get-Date)"
        $conn = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection
        Add-Content $ExtendedLogFile "################## CEMDatabaseConnect 2 $(Get-Date)"
        $conn.ConnectionString = "Driver={PostgreSQL Unicode};Server=xxx;Port=xxx;Database=xxx;Uid=xxx;Pwd=xxx;"
        Add-Content $ExtendedLogFile "################## CEMDatabaseConnect 3 $(Get-Date)"
        $conn.open()
        Add-Content $ExtendedLogFile "################## CEMDatabaseConnect 4 $(Get-Date)"
        $cmd = New-object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand($query,$conn)
        Add-Content $ExtendedLogFile "################## CEMDatabaseConnect 5 $(Get-Date)"
        $ds = New-Object system.Data.DataSet
        Add-Content $ExtendedLogFile "################## CEMDatabaseConnect 6 $(Get-Date)"
        (New-Object system.Data.odbc.odbcDataAdapter($cmd)).fill($ds) | out-null
        Add-Content $ExtendedLogFile "################## CEMDatabaseConnect 7 $(Get-Date)"
        $conn.close()
        Add-Content $ExtendedLogFile "################## CEMDatabaseConnect 8 $(Get-Date)"
        $ds.Tables[0]
        Add-Content $ExtendedLogFile "### 1.4 function CEMDatabaseConnect End $(Get-Date)"
    }
    Try
    {
        Add-Content $ExtendedLogFile "### 1.5 Try Start $(Get-Date)"
        $query = "select * from personnel limit 1"
        CEMDatabaseConnect -query $query
        Add-Content $ExtendedLogFile "### 1.5 Try End $(Get-Date)"
    }
    Catch
    {
        Add-Content $ExtendedLogFile "### 1.6 Catch Start $(Get-Date)"
        Add-Content $LogFile "Error Connecting to CEM Database | $(Get-Date) |"
        Add-Content $ExtendedLogFile "### 1.6 Catch End $(Get-Date)"
        Exit 1
        Break
    }
```

with added logging feature, as I am unable to pin point the error.

The deal is this: This code works absolutely fine on a local machine, however, once it got moved to a remote server, it either runs partially, with the rest of the code, but usually stops execution after few minutes, or it exits through the try catch exit 1 route.

logging this way suggest that there is issue with connection to the DB, and if I run tracer on the powershell, it throws error: query is required, which, doesnt make sense as there is a query provided and since it sometimes works, it makes even less sense.

As a cherry on top, with the added logging to the function, for some reason, it never runs sucessfully, always fails, almost as if logging was causing it.

Admittedly powershell isnt my strong suit, but I think the code is sound and really dont know what is wrong with it.

Privileges dont seem to be an issue, as well as DB creds and port all seem valid and open.

Any ideas?

Comment: `Param()` MUST be the first statement in your function definition, so your added logging is causing it to always run `throw` and fail. As for the rest of the script, try and output the actual `$error` message to your log file instead of suppressing it with catch. Can you add more detail about what "moved to a remote server" means? Can you run this part of the script interactively there?

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Ah of course, I have moved the logging and see what that reveals. Ill update you once I know more. thank you kind Sir
(the script was moved from a machine that was on the same network as the database, to a could server)